# Empty Java File not showing in NetBeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to open an empty java file but the option isn't there. I haven't even edited the settings. Can Someone tell me whats happened?

Comment: Hi! I think you'll need to give more information and make your question more precise so that others are able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what opening an empty file means, but I am guessing you just want to create a new file.

You can create and open for editing a New java file, using the menu option File -> New File ... . Select category Java and file type Java Class in the dialog.

The file will be empty except for a comment and the empty class definition. You can just delete the comment if you don't like it.

Comment: Don't worry. Turns out i'm a bit of an idiot most times.